# Uniqueness of the sum of roots of unity

Tags: roots-of-unity, kummer-theory

Everyone knows that the sum of all roots of unity $r_k$ equals to zero:
$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} r_k=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} e^{\frac{i2k\pi}{n}} =0$$

Does anyone know if it possible to prove that the equation below:

$$\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} a_k r_k=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} a_k e^{\frac{i2k\pi}{n}} =0$$ where $a_i\in N$ (non-negative integers)

has **only one** one solution: $a_0=a_1=...=a_{n-1}=constant$

Probably you can suggest me which direction to look in? May be Kummer rings theory can help or the simple prove exist.

Comment: There are other solutions like $ a_i = k$. So what constraints do you want on the coefficients?

Comment: For $n = 4$, we also have $ 1 \times 1 + 0 \times i + 1 \times (-1) + 0 \times (-i) = 0$, so your claim isn't true (as yet).

Comment: @Calvin Lin thx, i put the constraint

Comment: @peterwhy yes, i change the question $a_i$ are non-negative integers

Comment: Set $ n=2 $, $$ r_{0} = 1\text{ and }r_{1}=-1 $$ The equation $ a-b=0 $ has infinitely many solutions in $ \mathbb{R}^{2} \cdot $

Comment: Even if you restrict the coefficients to be $0$ or $1$, there are other solutions. For example, with $n=4$, take $r_0=r_2=1$ and $r_1=r_3=0$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin and Greg Martin you are right, thank you, my clime isn't true

Comment: Though I wonder if it's true for prime $n$, that all the $a_i$ are the same.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, the claim is true for prime $n$, and removing $k=0$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin what do you mean by "and removing $k=0$"? thank you

Comment: Ah sry, shouldn't have that part. How  much field theory do you know? Can you show that $ (x^p-1)/(x-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin not yet, but i understand to what direction to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n = 4$, $(a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3) = (1,1,1,1)$ is a solution, and $(1,0,1,0)$ is another solution from Calvin Lin in the comment above.

So the sum of the two solution vectors $(2,1,2,1)$ is another solution that consists of only positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make the assumption the coefficients are real (I think this is slightly more interesting posing an additional constraint), and that $n\ge 3$.

The idea linearity. Let
\begin{align*} 
{\bf s} &= (1,\cos(2\pi /n),\dots, \cos(2\pi (n-1)/n))\\
{\bf i} &= (0,\sin (2\pi/n),\dots, \sin (2\pi (n-1)/n))
\end{align*}

represent the real vectors consisting of the real and imaginary parts of $(1, \omega, \dots, \omega^{n-1})$ where $\omega = e^{2\pi i /n}$.

Next define $T:{\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^2$ by letting

$$ T {\bf a}  = ({\bf a}\cdot {\bf s} ,{\bf a} \cdot {\bf i}),$$

where  ${\bf a} = (a_0,\dots, a_{n-1})$. Then $T$ is linear and  $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j \omega^j=0$ if and only if $T{\bf a}=(0,0)$.

Since $n\ge 3$, it follows that $T$ is onto. Indeed: $Te_1 =(1,0)$ and $T e_2 = (\cos 2\pi/n,\sin 2\pi/n)$, which is linearly independent of $T e_1$.

Therefore by the rank + nullity Theorem, the null space of $T$ has dimension $n-2$.

To find a basis for the null space, you can choose  $n-2$  vectors of the form
$(x_2,y_2,1,0,\dots,0)$, $(x_3,y_3,0,1,0,\dots,0)$, ...,  $(x_{n-1},y_{n-1},0,\dots,0,1)$, where for each $j=2,\dots,n-2$, the constants  $x_j,y_j$ are chosen so that the resulting vector is orthogonal to both ${\bf s}$ and ${\bf i}$. Solving the equations we have

\begin{align*} &y_j = -\frac{\sin (2\pi j/n)}{\sin (2\pi /n)}\\
& x_j = -\cos(2\pi j/n) +\cos(2\pi/n)\frac{\sin (2\pi j/n)}{\sin (2\pi /n)}.
\end{align*}

In the case $n=4$, this gives the vectors
$(1,0,1,0),(0,1,0,1)$

Comment: +1. $x_j$ can be represented as

$$x_j = \frac{\sin(2\pi(j-1)/n)}{\sin(2\pi/n)}$$

Then by scaling the basis vectors of the null space by $\sin\frac{2\pi}n$, the $n-2$ vectors become

$$\pmatrix{
\sin\dfrac{2\pi (j-1)}n\\
-\sin \dfrac{2\pi j}n\\
\vdots\\
\sin\dfrac{2\pi}n\\
\vdots
}$$

Maybe it's more symmetric and has some geometric meaning, for further investigation.